# Please Clarify Spiritual Weapon effects using higher spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-slots

Please Clarify Spiritual Weapon effects using higher spell slots?

> Spiritual
> At Higher Levels. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd
> level or higher, the damage increases by 1d8 for every two slot levels
> above the 2nd.

So SW does 1d8 + spellcasting ability modifier at base effect. Does using a 3rd level spell make SW deal 2d8 + ScAM or do you have to use a 4thlevel spell slot to do so?

Comment: I have to agree that this is a very confusing way to write how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 3rd level slot is only one slot level above the 2nd, so it does not give you any bonus damage.

A 4th level slot is two slots levels above the 2nd, so the damage increases by 1d8.

At 6th and 8th level slots the damage increases by 2d8 and 3d8 respectively, since they are four and six slot levels above the 2nd.

Comment: The wording could have been done so much better. "When you cast the spell, the damage increases by 1d8 for every two spell slot levels above the 2nd." This is exactly why I prefer a Mana, Magic Point or Spell Point system over spell slots. (X) Spell cost (Y) MP and you get (Z) MP per day. Modding Spells could cost addition MP or so.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Yeah it doesn't make much sense, I'm guessing they did it to mirror the wording they use elsewhere.